# Docker AWS Elastic beanstalk no error in local machine docker build but spacy NLP hanging forever when put on server

Tags: docker, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Like the title. I have tested my docker on my local machine using docker build -t container-name and everything worked fine without any errors. Once I uploaded to beanstalk via CLI EB it fails. I have figured that there is one part where I run spacy's chinese NLP where it fails. Everything else is working fine but there seem to be no errors in the logs or anything unusual I can tell to understand how to debug this.

I have tried every possibility and looked through the web to no avail. There is one time when the full logs from the EB showed 'memoryerror' which I cannot recreate under any circumstance but that is all the clue I have. Here are the logs:

```
    > ---------------------------------------- /var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/eb-29f07434a6e4-stdouterr.log
    > ----------------------------------------
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:29] "POST /food_autocomplete HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:30] "POST /food_autocomplete HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.4.206 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.27.83 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:34] "POST /food_nutrient_modal HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:329:
    > UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator CountVectorizer from version
    > 0.21.2 when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.   warnings.warn(
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:329:
    > UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator TfidfTransformer from
    > version 0.21.2 when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking
    > code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.   warnings.warn(
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:329:
    > UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator LogisticRegression from
    > version 0.21.2 when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking
    > code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.   warnings.warn(
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:329:
    > UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator Pipeline from version 0.21.2
    > when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid
    > results. Use at your own risk.   warnings.warn(
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:329:
    > UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator CountVectorizer from version
    > 0.21.2 when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.   warnings.warn(
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:329:
    > UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator TfidfTransformer from
    > version 0.21.2 when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking
    > code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.   warnings.warn(
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:329:
    > UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator LogisticRegression from
    > version 0.21.2 when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking
    > code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.   warnings.warn(
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:329:
    > UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator Pipeline from version 0.21.2
    > when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid
    > results. Use at your own risk.   warnings.warn(
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:36] "POST /smart_suggestions HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:38] "POST /food_nutrient_modal HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:39] "POST /addfood HTTP/1.1" 204 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:40] "POST /food_table_generate HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:42] "POST /personal_submit HTTP/1.1" 204 -
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/util.py:271: UserWarning:
    > [W031] Model 'en_Reported_outcome_NLP' (0.0.0) requires spaCy v2.2 and
    > is incompatible with the current spaCy version (2.3.0). This may lead
    > to unexpected results or runtime errors. To resolve this, download a
    > newer compatible model or retrain your custom model with the current
    > spaCy version. For more details and available updates, run: python -m
    > spacy validate   warnings.warn(warn_msg)
    > 172.31.4.206 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.27.83 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:47] "POST /food_nlp_onthefly HTTP/1.1" 200 - Building prefix dict from the default dictionary ...
    > Dumping model to file cache /tmp/jieba.cache Loading model cost 0.990
    > seconds. Prefix dict has been built successfully.  * Serving Flask app
    > "base" (lazy loading)  * Environment: development  * Debug mode: off
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:329:
    > UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator CountVectorizer from version
    > 0.21.2 when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.   warnings.warn(
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:329:
    > UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator TfidfTransformer from
    > version 0.21.2 when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking
    > code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.   warnings.warn(
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/deprecation.py:143:
    > FutureWarning: The sklearn.linear_model.logistic module is  deprecated
    > in version 0.22 and will be removed in version 0.24. The corresponding
    > classes / functions should instead be imported from
    > sklearn.linear_model. Anything that cannot be imported from
    > sklearn.linear_model is now part of the private API.  
    > warnings.warn(message, FutureWarning)
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:329:
    > UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator LogisticRegression from
    > version 0.21.2 when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking
    > code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.   warnings.warn(
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:329:
    > UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator Pipeline from version 0.21.2
    > when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid
    > results. Use at your own risk.   warnings.warn(  * Running on
    > http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
    > 172.31.4.206 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:23:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:23:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.27.83 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:23:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.4.206 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.27.83 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.4.206 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.27.83 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:21] "GET /personal HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:21] "POST /usertimezone HTTP/1.1" 204 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:22] "GET /static/img/favicon.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:29] "POST /food_autocomplete HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:30] "POST /food_autocomplete HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.4.206 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.27.83 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:34] "POST /food_nutrient_modal HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:329:
    > UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator CountVectorizer from version
    > 0.21.2 when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.   warnings.warn(
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:329:
    > UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator TfidfTransformer from
    > version 0.21.2 when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking
    > code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.   warnings.warn(
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:329:
    > UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator LogisticRegression from
    > version 0.21.2 when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking
    > code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.   warnings.warn(
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:329:
    > UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator Pipeline from version 0.21.2
    > when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid
    > results. Use at your own risk.   warnings.warn(
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:329:
    > UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator CountVectorizer from version
    > 0.21.2 when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.   warnings.warn(
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:329:
    > UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator TfidfTransformer from
    > version 0.21.2 when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking
    > code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.   warnings.warn(
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:329:
    > UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator LogisticRegression from
    > version 0.21.2 when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking
    > code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.   warnings.warn(
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:329:
    > UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator Pipeline from version 0.21.2
    > when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid
    > results. Use at your own risk.   warnings.warn(
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:36] "POST /smart_suggestions HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:38] "POST /food_nutrient_modal HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:39] "POST /addfood HTTP/1.1" 204 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:40] "POST /food_table_generate HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:42] "POST /personal_submit HTTP/1.1" 204 -
    > /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/util.py:271: UserWarning:
    > [W031] Model 'en_Reported_outcome_NLP' (0.0.0) requires spaCy v2.2 and
    > is incompatible with the current spaCy version (2.3.0). This may lead
    > to unexpected results or runtime errors. To resolve this, download a
    > newer compatible model or retrain your custom model with the current
    > spaCy version. For more details and available updates, run: python -m
    > spacy validate   warnings.warn(warn_msg)
    > 172.31.4.206 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.27.83 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    > 172.31.43.156 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:24:47] "POST /food_nlp_onthefly HTTP/1.1" 200 - Building prefix dict from the default dictionary ...
    > Dumping model to file cache /tmp/jieba.cache Loading model cost 0.990
    > seconds. Prefix dict has been built successfully.
    > 
    > 
    > ---------------------------------------- /var/log/docker-events.log
    > ---------------------------------------- 2020-07-07T17:08:43.222801211Z image pull python:3.8.2-buster
    > name=agitated_hugle) 2020-07-07T17:09:46.255907751Z container create
    > 5e3269e6db83eb7da60b4f011e0038ee847a83a16200482885ccdfc1ee53f4b3
    > (image=sha256:938ea8d987340203ade469ba4cbf79ea7af3626bc521c6e4667959b700877892,
    > name=interesting_vaughan) 2020-07-07T17:09:46.256131915Z container
    > attach
    > 5e3269e6db83eb7da60b4f011e0038ee847a83a16200482885ccdfc1ee53f4b3
    > (image=sha256:938ea8d987340203ade469ba4cbf79ea7af3626bc521c6e4667959b700877892,
    > name=interesting_vaughan) 2020-07-07T17:09:46.295742501Z network
    > connect
    > 0313ee36f6c330fb7f0435db1997443faa3aec1cf0aa895a68bce628065eece5
    > (container=5e3269e6db83eb7da60b4f011e0038ee847a83a16200482885ccdfc1ee53f4b3,
    > name=bridge, type=bridge) 2020-07-07T17:09:46.734903605Z container
    > start 5e3269e6db83eb7da60b4f011e0038ee847a83a16200482885ccdfc1ee53f4b3
    > (image=sha256:938ea8d987340203ade469ba4cbf79ea7af3626bc521c6e4667959b700877892,
    > name=interesting_vaughan) 2020-07-07T17:09:49.122315926Z container die
    > 5e3269e6db83eb7da60b4f011e0038ee847a83a16200482885ccdfc1ee53f4b3
    > (exitCode=0,
    > image=sha256:938ea8d987340203ade469ba4cbf79ea7af3626bc521c6e4667959b700877892,
    > name=interesting_vaughan) 2020-07-07T17:09:49.171805355Z network
    > disconnect
    > 0313ee36f6c330fb7f0435db1997443faa3aec1cf0aa895a68bce628065eece5
    > (container=5e3269e6db83eb7da60b4f011e0038ee847a83a16200482885ccdfc1ee53f4b3,
    > name=bridge, type=bridge) 2020-07-07T17:09:49.813444357Z container
    > destroy
    > 5e3269e6db83eb7da60b4f011e0038ee847a83a16200482885ccdfc1ee53f4b3
    > (image=sha256:938ea8d987340203ade469ba4cbf79ea7af3626bc521c6e4667959b700877892,
    > name=interesting_vaughan) 2020-07-07T17:09:49.831035003Z container
    > create
    > 55647e02051fdd853af507483370a89e29e916ef618c0f8dff83b88054d157ed
    > (image=sha256:8c7a43e1019f42bc7153ec0b4d142740110250db72ae1475d44d3fa9d16e771d,
    > name=friendly_goldstine) 2020-07-07T17:09:49.831391340Z container
    > attach
    > 55647e02051fdd853af507483370a89e29e916ef618c0f8dff83b88054d157ed
    > (image=sha256:8c7a43e1019f42bc7153ec0b4d142740110250db72ae1475d44d3fa9d16e771d,
    > name=friendly_goldstine) 2020-07-07T17:09:49.884733812Z network
    > connect
    > 0313ee36f6c330fb7f0435db1997443faa3aec1cf0aa895a68bce628065eece5
    > (container=55647e02051fdd853af507483370a89e29e916ef618c0f8dff83b88054d157ed,
    > name=bridge, type=bridge) 2020-07-07T17:09:50.290165549Z container
    > start 55647e02051fdd853af507483370a89e29e916ef618c0f8dff83b88054d157ed
    > (image=sha256:8c7a43e1019f42bc7153ec0b4d142740110250db72ae1475d44d3fa9d16e771d,
    > name=friendly_goldstine) 2020-07-07T17:09:53.138031459Z container die
    > 55647e02051fdd853af507483370a89e29e916ef618c0f8dff83b88054d157ed
    > (exitCode=0,
    > image=sha256:8c7a43e1019f42bc7153ec0b4d142740110250db72ae1475d44d3fa9d16e771d,
    > name=friendly_goldstine) 2020-07-07T17:09:53.195435239Z network
    > disconnect
    > 0313ee36f6c330fb7f0435db1997443faa3aec1cf0aa895a68bce628065eece5
    > (container=55647e02051fdd853af507483370a89e29e916ef618c0f8dff83b88054d157ed,
    > name=bridge, type=bridge) 2020-07-07T17:09:53.294312475Z container
    > destroy
    > 55647e02051fdd853af507483370a89e29e916ef618c0f8dff83b88054d157ed
    > (image=sha256:8c7a43e1019f42bc7153ec0b4d142740110250db72ae1475d44d3fa9d16e771d,
    > name=friendly_goldstine) 2020-07-07T17:09:53.313349292Z container
    > create
    > c3c43c4db5b583beb1fbe2161bd73b7a6ea4411b58366f4f043db51b6e2412b0
    > (image=sha256:f973e6783f1cb4b492fdf837be75718d5cd396707432a9dbebab795c7a8f1c29,
    > name=crazy_cartwright) 2020-07-07T17:09:53.313571816Z container attach
    > c3c43c4db5b583beb1fbe2161bd73b7a6ea4411b58366f4f043db51b6e2412b0
    > (image=sha256:f973e6783f1cb4b492fdf837be75718d5cd396707432a9dbebab795c7a8f1c29,
    > name=crazy_cartwright) 2020-07-07T17:09:53.362840973Z network connect
    > 0313ee36f6c330fb7f0435db1997443faa3aec1cf0aa895a68bce628065eece5
    > (container=c3c43c4db5b583beb1fbe2161bd73b7a6ea4411b58366f4f043db51b6e2412b0,
    > name=bridge, type=bridge) 2020-07-07T17:09:53.774896296Z container
    > start c3c43c4db5b583beb1fbe2161bd73b7a6ea4411b58366f4f043db51b6e2412b0
    > (image=sha256:f973e6783f1cb4b492fdf837be75718d5cd396707432a9dbebab795c7a8f1c29,
    > name=crazy_cartwright) 2020-07-07T17:10:30.678618014Z container die
    > c3c43c4db5b583beb1fbe2161bd73b7a6ea4411b58366f4f043db51b6e2412b0
    > (exitCode=0,
    > image=sha256:f973e6783f1cb4b492fdf837be75718d5cd396707432a9dbebab795c7a8f1c29,
    > name=crazy_cartwright) 2020-07-07T17:10:30.740972059Z network
    > disconnect
    > 0313ee36f6c330fb7f0435db1997443faa3aec1cf0aa895a68bce628065eece5
    > (container=c3c43c4db5b583beb1fbe2161bd73b7a6ea4411b58366f4f043db51b6e2412b0,
    > name=bridge, type=bridge) 2020-07-07T17:10:31.134171606Z container
    > destroy
    > c3c43c4db5b583beb1fbe2161bd73b7a6ea4411b58366f4f043db51b6e2412b0
    > (image=sha256:f973e6783f1cb4b492fdf837be75718d5cd396707432a9dbebab795c7a8f1c29,
    > name=crazy_cartwright) 2020-07-07T17:10:33.387455304Z container create
    > d7445fa259c0281ef92909bae68e0ef640122c3c8aadc8523ccd0ab3168cb439
    > (image=sha256:bbe93b4133f847fb8b7217d07fea76d7954db093dced90575f5904437b41bf3e,
    > name=angry_hermann) 2020-07-07T17:10:33.476870016Z container destroy
    > d7445fa259c0281ef92909bae68e0ef640122c3c8aadc8523ccd0ab3168cb439
    > (image=sha256:bbe93b4133f847fb8b7217d07fea76d7954db093dced90575f5904437b41bf3e,
    > name=angry_hermann) 2020-07-07T17:10:33.494062931Z container create
    > bc23ff300c23cff0b00d12faab49a790a21b9e3bdc8879039afd236163de3cca
    > (image=sha256:e4dac3e5b2864c76b1be5c0a9931a23c29d30896eb3deae344dce336ddbb11e5,
    > name=admiring_driscoll) 2020-07-07T17:10:33.573500812Z container
    > destroy
    > bc23ff300c23cff0b00d12faab49a790a21b9e3bdc8879039afd236163de3cca
    > (image=sha256:e4dac3e5b2864c76b1be5c0a9931a23c29d30896eb3deae344dce336ddbb11e5,
    > name=admiring_driscoll) 2020-07-07T17:10:33.592409924Z image tag
    > sha256:a01459d6ad267dabc254bb7b7cd75af0179b81cfdf6762d9bfa13691b2f2d536
    > (name=aws_beanstalk/staging-app:latest) 2020-07-07T17:10:36.173605128Z
    > container create
    > 65f83c0b3683725ef5c6e633ef3302f8ee853e4edd5478c900a2a27086421a7e
    > (image=a01459d6ad26, name=goofy_easley) 2020-07-07T17:10:36.223247839Z
    > network connect
    > 0313ee36f6c330fb7f0435db1997443faa3aec1cf0aa895a68bce628065eece5
    > (container=65f83c0b3683725ef5c6e633ef3302f8ee853e4edd5478c900a2a27086421a7e,
    > name=bridge, type=bridge) 2020-07-07T17:10:36.637664357Z container
    > start 65f83c0b3683725ef5c6e633ef3302f8ee853e4edd5478c900a2a27086421a7e
    > (image=a01459d6ad26, name=goofy_easley) 2020-07-07T17:10:41.964896576Z
    > image tag
    > sha256:a01459d6ad267dabc254bb7b7cd75af0179b81cfdf6762d9bfa13691b2f2d536
    > (name=aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest) 2020-07-07T17:10:42.012166449Z
    > image untag
    > sha256:a01459d6ad267dabc254bb7b7cd75af0179b81cfdf6762d9bfa13691b2f2d536
    > (name=sha256:a01459d6ad267dabc254bb7b7cd75af0179b81cfdf6762d9bfa13691b2f2d536)
    > 2020-07-07T17:10:42.740687237Z image tag
    > sha256:a01459d6ad267dabc254bb7b7cd75af0179b81cfdf6762d9bfa13691b2f2d536
    > (name=aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest) 2020-07-07T17:10:42.836810391Z
    > image tag
    > sha256:4f7cd4269fa9900fe43f5c0db2267926ee972cac6cec74a92b9136e49f8b3489
    > (name=python:3.8.2-buster) 2020-07-07T17:16:40.255804571Z container
    > die 65f83c0b3683725ef5c6e633ef3302f8ee853e4edd5478c900a2a27086421a7e
    > (exitCode=137, image=a01459d6ad26, name=goofy_easley)
    > 2020-07-07T17:16:40.376674654Z network disconnect
    > 0313ee36f6c330fb7f0435db1997443faa3aec1cf0aa895a68bce628065eece5
    > (container=65f83c0b3683725ef5c6e633ef3302f8ee853e4edd5478c900a2a27086421a7e,
    > name=bridge, type=bridge) 2020-07-07T17:16:43.031775619Z network
    > connect
    > 0313ee36f6c330fb7f0435db1997443faa3aec1cf0aa895a68bce628065eece5
    > (container=65f83c0b3683725ef5c6e633ef3302f8ee853e4edd5478c900a2a27086421a7e,
    > name=bridge, type=bridge) 2020-07-07T17:16:43.789437781Z container
    > start 65f83c0b3683725ef5c6e633ef3302f8ee853e4edd5478c900a2a27086421a7e
    > (image=a01459d6ad26, name=goofy_easley) 2020-07-07T17:17:07.998859712Z
    > container die
    > 65f83c0b3683725ef5c6e633ef3302f8ee853e4edd5478c900a2a27086421a7e
    > (exitCode=137, image=a01459d6ad26, name=goofy_easley)
    > 2020-07-07T17:17:08.142891259Z network disconnect
    > 0313ee36f6c330fb7f0435db1997443faa3aec1cf0aa895a68bce628065eece5
    > (container=65f83c0b3683725ef5c6e633ef3302f8ee853e4edd5478c900a2a27086421a7e,
    > name=bridge, type=bridge) 2020-07-07T17:17:10.700159940Z network
    > connect
    > 0313ee36f6c330fb7f0435db1997443faa3aec1cf0aa895a68bce628065eece5
    > (container=65f83c0b3683725ef5c6e633ef3302f8ee853e4edd5478c900a2a27086421a7e,
    > name=bridge, type=bridge) 2020-07-07T17:17:11.346017877Z container
    > start 65f83c0b3683725ef5c6e633ef3302f8ee853e4edd5478c900a2a27086421a7e
    > (image=a01459d6ad26, name=goofy_easley) 2020-07-07T17:23:30.234526457Z
    > image tag
    > sha256:a01459d6ad267dabc254bb7b7cd75af0179b81cfdf6762d9bfa13691b2f2d536
    > (name=aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest) 2020-07-07T17:23:30.281059141Z
    > image tag
    > sha256:4f7cd4269fa9900fe43f5c0db2267926ee972cac6cec74a92b9136e49f8b3489
    > (name=python:3.8.2-buster) 2020-07-07T17:23:32.677604215Z image pull
    > python:3.8.2-buster (name=python) 2020-07-07T17:23:33.765347130Z image
    > tag
    > sha256:a01459d6ad267dabc254bb7b7cd75af0179b81cfdf6762d9bfa13691b2f2d536
    > (name=aws_beanstalk/staging-app:latest) 2020-07-07T17:23:34.638892876Z
    > image tag
    > sha256:a01459d6ad267dabc254bb7b7cd75af0179b81cfdf6762d9bfa13691b2f2d536
    > (name=aws_beanstalk/staging-app:latest) 2020-07-07T17:23:34.721945923Z
    > container create
    > 29f07434a6e45cb922cdde01f615fadb13962602050e7330821ca7efe4234e97
    > (image=a01459d6ad26, name=pensive_taussig)
    > 2020-07-07T17:23:34.777140048Z network connect
    > 0313ee36f6c330fb7f0435db1997443faa3aec1cf0aa895a68bce628065eece5
    > (container=29f07434a6e45cb922cdde01f615fadb13962602050e7330821ca7efe4234e97,
    > name=bridge, type=bridge) 2020-07-07T17:23:35.225632098Z container
    > start 29f07434a6e45cb922cdde01f615fadb13962602050e7330821ca7efe4234e97
    > (image=a01459d6ad26, name=pensive_taussig)
    > 2020-07-07T17:23:40.730637840Z container kill
    > 65f83c0b3683725ef5c6e633ef3302f8ee853e4edd5478c900a2a27086421a7e
    > (image=a01459d6ad26, name=goofy_easley, signal=15)
    > 2020-07-07T17:23:50.749346961Z container kill
    > 65f83c0b3683725ef5c6e633ef3302f8ee853e4edd5478c900a2a27086421a7e
    > (image=a01459d6ad26, name=goofy_easley, signal=9)
    > 2020-07-07T17:23:51.007134732Z container die
    > 65f83c0b3683725ef5c6e633ef3302f8ee853e4edd5478c900a2a27086421a7e
    > (exitCode=137, image=a01459d6ad26, name=goofy_easley)
    > 2020-07-07T17:23:51.064061323Z network disconnect
    > 0313ee36f6c330fb7f0435db1997443faa3aec1cf0aa895a68bce628065eece5
    > (container=65f83c0b3683725ef5c6e633ef3302f8ee853e4edd5478c900a2a27086421a7e,
    > name=bridge, type=bridge) 2020-07-07T17:23:51.079435605Z container
    > stop 65f83c0b3683725ef5c6e633ef3302f8ee853e4edd5478c900a2a27086421a7e
    > (image=a01459d6ad26, name=goofy_easley) 2020-07-07T17:23:51.254045082Z
    > container destroy
    > 65f83c0b3683725ef5c6e633ef3302f8ee853e4edd5478c900a2a27086421a7e
    > (image=a01459d6ad26, name=goofy_easley) 2020-07-07T17:23:51.303433852Z
    > image tag
    > sha256:a01459d6ad267dabc254bb7b7cd75af0179b81cfdf6762d9bfa13691b2f2d536
    > (name=aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest) 2020-07-07T17:23:51.350189423Z
    > image untag
    > sha256:a01459d6ad267dabc254bb7b7cd75af0179b81cfdf6762d9bfa13691b2f2d536
    > (name=sha256:a01459d6ad267dabc254bb7b7cd75af0179b81cfdf6762d9bfa13691b2f2d536)
    > 2020-07-07T17:25:13.302167787Z container die
    > 29f07434a6e45cb922cdde01f615fadb13962602050e7330821ca7efe4234e97
    > (exitCode=137, image=a01459d6ad26, name=pensive_taussig)
    > 2020-07-07T17:25:13.478841157Z network disconnect
    > 0313ee36f6c330fb7f0435db1997443faa3aec1cf0aa895a68bce628065eece5
    > (container=29f07434a6e45cb922cdde01f615fadb13962602050e7330821ca7efe4234e97,
    > name=bridge, type=bridge) 2020-07-07T17:25:16.050466851Z network
    > connect
    > 0313ee36f6c330fb7f0435db1997443faa3aec1cf0aa895a68bce628065eece5
    > (container=29f07434a6e45cb922cdde01f615fadb13962602050e7330821ca7efe4234e97,
    > name=bridge, type=bridge) 2020-07-07T17:25:16.806548828Z container
    > start 29f07434a6e45cb922cdde01f615fadb13962602050e7330821ca7efe4234e97
    > (image=a01459d6ad26, name=pensive_taussig)
    > 
    > 
    > ---------------------------------------- /var/log/docker
    > ---------------------------------------- Jul  7 17:08:13 ip-172-31-2-67 docker: time="2020-07-07
    > type="*events.TaskDelete" Jul  7 17:17:07 ip-172-31-2-67 docker:
    > time="2020-07-07T17:17:07.984841127Z" level=info msg="ignoring event"
    > module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete
    > type="*events.TaskDelete" Jul  7 17:23:50 ip-172-31-2-67 docker:
    > time="2020-07-07T17:23:50.730877626Z" level=info msg="Container
    > 65f83c0b3683725ef5c6e633ef3302f8ee853e4edd5478c900a2a27086421a7e
    > failed to exit within 10 seconds of signal 15 - using the force" Jul 
    > 7 17:23:51 ip-172-31-2-67 docker:
    > time="2020-07-07T17:23:51.007035781Z" level=info msg="ignoring event"
    > module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete
    > type="*events.TaskDelete" Jul  7 17:25:13 ip-172-31-2-67 docker:
    > time="2020-07-07T17:25:13.295457935Z" level=info msg="ignoring event"
    > module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete
    > type="*events.TaskDelete"
    > 
    > 
    > 
    > ---------------------------------------- /var/log/nginx/error.log
    > ---------------------------------------- 2020/07/07 17:16:38 [error] 5596#0: *144 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading
    > response header from upstream, client: 172.31.43.156, server: ,
    > request: "POST /food_nlp_onthefly HTTP/1.1", upstream:
    > "http://172.17.0.2:5000/food_nlp_onthefly", host:
    > "healthbook.humango.co", referrer:
    > "https://healthbook.humango.co/personal" 2020/07/07 17:16:39 [error]
    > 5596#0: *131 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading
    > response header from upstream, client: 172.31.43.156, server: ,
    > request: "POST /food_nlp_onthefly HTTP/1.1", upstream:
    > "http://172.17.0.2:5000/food_nlp_onthefly", host:
    > "healthbook.humango.co", referrer:
    > "https://healthbook.humango.co/personal" 2020/07/07 17:16:47 [error]
    > 6480#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting
    > to upstream, client: 172.31.4.206, server: , request: "GET /
    > HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:5000/", host: "172.31.2.67"
    > 2020/07/07 17:16:47 [error] 6480#0: *3 connect() failed (111:
    > Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
    > 172.31.43.156, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:5000/", host: "172.31.2.67" 2020/07/07 17:16:47
    > [error] 6480#0: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while
    > connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.27.83, server: , request: "GET
    > / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:5000/", host: "172.31.2.67"
    > 2020/07/07 17:17:07 [error] 6480#0: *7 upstream prematurely closed
    > connection while reading response header from upstream, client:
    > 172.31.43.156, server: , request: "POST /food_table_generate HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:5000/food_table_generate",
    > host: "healthbook.humango.co", referrer:
    > "https://healthbook.humango.co/personal"
```

Comment: When you login to the EB instance, and manually try to build and run your docker, does it work?

Comment: @Marcin I used CLI EB to eb deploy is there a difference that way? The thing is it does run everything is normal except one small part of the code where it just hangs. Yet, that parts works normally on my docker when I run it locally. I am wondering if that has to do with the memory limit of my t2-micro container since it is free-tier but I cannot believe I am using that much memory it makes no sense to me :/ please advise!

Comment: Hi. I mean that when you ssh into the EB instance and manually run/build the docker as you would on your local workstation. This way you can monitor more closely the build process, memory usage etc.

Comment: @Marcin so you're saying i can see how much memory I am using if I run docker build -t name? Thanks!

Comment: Sadly, I don't know what is the cause of your error. But trying to run the commands/docker manually from the EB instance is a common troubleshooting technique for EB. Basically try to manually setup your container on the EB instance. This way you can verify if it works when done manually, or it fails only when deployed automatically through `eb` command.

Comment: @Marcin thank you for your help. I have found the problem!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for anyone who somehow has the same problem:

The problem for me was that it worked on my local machine but not on AWS EB but without errors. The problem was the memoryerror mentioned above. I was using a free tier hence my memory limit was at 1gb and AWS EB crashes once you exceed that limit.

There are two ways to fix it that is quite obvious but was not obvious to me in the first place:

1. Expand your tier to one with higher memory capacity
2. Make your program more memory efficient

I did the latter and the problem was solved.

Some useful commands to help you debug:

```
eb health
```

to check on the memory cpu usage of your AWS EB

```
docker stats container-name
```

this lets you check on the memory usage in your docker in your local machine.
I hope this helps. I was quite hopeless since I couldn't find any clues to (without any error log)

Cheers!